# JWT refresh token with jjwt

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

recently I've started my project in SpringBoot and Kotlin and I wanted to create user management system. After a few searches, I've looked at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE) video regarding the implementation of JWT tokens for the authentication process.

Everything seems to work perfectly, besides the fact that currently, I need to pass the username and password in each authentication - which means that the client calling the API needs to either store it or ask for it each time.

After looking in [this](https://medium.com/kaliop/3-ways-to-automatically-renew-an-user-session-per-token-jwt-552616e1f094) article it seems that option 3 is actually what I'm looking for. From what I'm understanding the process of authentication should be as follow:

- a client calls the authentication method
- 2 tokens are returned - 1 with a short period which is the authentication token, and one with a longer period which allows renewal of the authentication token.
- Once the authentication token is expired, the client will as to renew the expired token using only those tokens without the original details of the user.

I have 2 questions in this regards:

1. From the security perspective - what will happen if a hacker "catches" those 2 tokens? that basically means that the hacker can authenticate as this user from now on without any problem - isn't it?
2. More or implementation question, from what I could see, `jjwt` does not support this functionality (as I can read the information from the token as long as the token did not expire). From my search, I couldn't find something that gives it "out of the box" - is there a standard that to implement this functionally?

Comment: Hello! Did you answered your question later. I'm dealing with the same.